# I'm trying to do a todolist, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just started to learn JavaScript and I have an assignment to do a todo list.
Here are the requirements:

1. The todo list will contain tasks we want to do.
2. Initially the list will contains these predefined items (see mockup below)
   a. Register to Full Stack Web Course
   b. Attend Selection Day
   c. Go see X-Men apocalypse movie
3. When a task is done it will be marked by displaying the task text with a
   strikethrough font and gray color - use a suitable CSS class.
   a. Item (b) in the list should be displayed as done.
4. User can add a new item to the list by entering text into an entry box allowing one line of text with the length required to be between 6 and 42 chars and then pressing the “Add” button.
5. New items will be added to the top of the list.
6. Use pure JavaScript - no frameworks.

*** I've done all of these things but it doesn't work. I can't mark any of tasks done unless the action is taken manually on the html box.
 Here is the code so far:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/amir_nazarov/0tf5gwky/24/][1]
```

Sorry for my English and thank you for the help.

Comment: Include your code in the post here on Stack Overflow please, don't just link to jsfiddle. Stack Overflow and jsfiddle are not affiliated with one another, and if your fiddle or jsfiddle goes down or becomes unassociated with this post for some reason, people who land on this post in the future will not be able to reference your original code. It's just as easy to add to SO as it is jsfiddle, btw.

Comment: Does this work like you expect it to? https://jsfiddle.net/0tf5gwky/25/

Comment: sorry bracking the rules or what ever i done in the post, I'm new in all this and also in the site. and yes it's perfect!!! but why it didn't work for me what I have writed?

Comment: All I did was move your JS from the JS panel into the HTML panel. So I didn't change anything in your code. Not sure why that was necessary, must be something with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code at the beginning of your JavaScript, (the one that sets up the strikethrough capabilities) never gets called.

To fix this you have to:

1. Place that code inside of a `function`, like the code after it, and
2. Add that `function` to the `body`'s `onclick` attribute to make it be called when the page is loaded.

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8v4Lp4q/). I think it achieves what you were after.

Comment: thank you now i understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to bind the click event to the existent `ol li` elements they aren't yet ready. Wait to the content to be loaded to attach the event listener. Also you should attach the listener to the new `li` elements created with add button.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var task = document.querySelectorAll('ol li');
  /* go loop all the way- on tasks */
 for (var i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
   
  task[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
       event.target.classList.toggle("checked");
  }, false);
 }
});





function todoList(){
document.getElementById("todoInput").value
var item    = document.getElementById('todoInput').value
if(item.length >= 6 && item.length <= 42)
{
var text    = document.createTextNode(item)
var newItem = document.createElement('li')
 newItem.appendChild(text)
  
  newItem.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
       event.target.classList.toggle("checked");
  }, false);
 document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem)
 var list = document.getElementById("todoList");
list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);
}
else
{
alert("The text is in the worng length")
}
}
```

```css
ol {

}
ol li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;

}
ol li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
ol li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
ol li.checked::before {
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <body>
      <title>To Do List</title>
      <h1>To Do List</h1>
          <form id="todoForm">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a task here" id="todoInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add</button>
          </form>
          <hr>
          <ol id="todoList">
               <li>Register to Full Stack Web Course</li>
               <li class="checked">Attend Selection Day</li>
              <li>Go see X-Men apocalypse movie</li>
          </ol>
       <script src="js/main.js"></script>   
       </body>
```